# Second hand SolarEdge 10000H-US Grid tied inverter

Tags: solar, inverter

My question is how I can safely test whether this inverter is functioning. It requires dc optimizers and I haven't purchased them yet but before I go too far purchasing compatible optimizers, I want to make sure this unit is working.

PN Solaredge SE10000H-US000BNU4.
https://www.solaris-shop.com/solaredge-hd-wave-se10000h-us-10kw-inverter/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwl_SHBhCQARIsAFIFRVWevtKZ5Nk0vwbzXERdQWSAxV8vPVyQlN7PFR1ZDL_3jIi5xiUy2c8aAgfBEALw_wcB

It's got L1/L2/N and I'm just wondering can I hook up the A/C side and leave the DC unconnected, then if it has power I'd be able to put an ethernet cable in and try to communicate with it. If I need to purchase a few dc optimizers to test this then I will.

We will have an engineer drawing up plans for us before proceeding but I'd like to know asap if I have a working inverter.

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it only needs AC power to configure. That would make sense, since one might need to configure it at night.

Note that it has some sort of configuration SIM card, as well as a cloud-based monitoring system.  That might indicate some sort of licensing/CRM feature to prevent the unit from being sold on the aftermarket, or some sort of dealer-based control to oblige you to work with authorized dealers.

It might be worth asking the factory "If I bought one and later sold it used, will it work?"

Comment: One thing I do not like about so called smart devices.  You don't really own them, you only get to pay to use them for how long a company decides.

Comment: For what it is worth, SolarEdge is fine with having the owner of the inverter be their own installer. Create a SolarEdge installer account suppling your name and address as the company's name and address. If you have trouble, contact their support. With physical access to the inverter, you can (re-)configure it to use your installer account.  Now if the unit has the cellular communication module installed, and you want to use it, I think that bill falls on the installer (which would be you), and am not sure how to get that set up to work. But you can always use ethernet.